# Firebase Phone Number Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

Firebase Phone Number Authentication is not working for some mobile numbers sometimes. **Console.log** is showing the "sms sent" as I have put it there and also the **confirmationResult** but sms is not reaching to the mobile number in that instant or it reaches after a long time (20 minutes or 30 minutes). This thing is happening only for some mobile numbers, sometimes.

I am having the following code.

How can this problem be reduced ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class LoginView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {contact:''};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    var phoneNumber = '+91' + this.state.cnct;
    firebase.auth().languageCode = 'en';
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('confirm-button', {
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': function(response) {
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
           console.log(response);
        }
    });    
    var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const self = this;
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
      console.log("Sms sent");
      console.log(confirmationResult);
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      self.props.state.variables.confirmation = confirmationResult;
    }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Too much otp verification code are sent.. Try again after some time");
       console.log("Sms not sent!");
    });
  }
  render() {
    <div>
       <h1>Login</h1>
       <input type="text" label="Mobile Number" value={this.state.contact} maxLength="10"/>
       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Login via OTP</button>
    </div>
  }
}
export {LoginView};
```

Comment: If you are experiencing delays, try reaching out to Firebase Support about this: https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: yes maybe I'm experiencing delays and that's why I's searching if anyways I can reduce this problem for now. Is there something needed in the code ?

Comment: If you are acutally get the SMS messages but getting them late, then I doubt it is client side code related.